# Google data studio's can't export in a pdf with all data in table

Tags: looker-studio

Can someone pls help me about exporting google data studio into a pdf ,The problem is i can't export all of the data from this table (picture is attached) because there's a missing part after its come out to PDF (Scrolling needed part)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoVYm.png)

Answer (score 1):

Export to PDF is pretty much like screen printing the page so your options for PDF are things like decreasing font size or removing the images to increase the amount of rows you can get on one page.

Alternatively you could restrict the table to rows 1-20 and then create a second page with has rows 21+ on it to show that data.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there's no out of box solution from Google DataStudio. However, you can do the following workaround :

Increase the page height.  To do this, Go to Menu > Page > Current page settings > Style > Height (px). Increase the height.
Then, extend the height of the table to the desired level.

(Of course, this workaround works with like 100/150 rows but not 1000s).

Please don't just right click on the page and adjust the height. It'll apply the height to all the pages then.

Answer (score 0):

you can export the whole data but in csv file not pdf.
just right click on your results -> Export -> CSV

in my opinion the excel file is much better than pdf because it gives you a lot of options and filters to arrange your data and understand it